# Remove Duplicates Linq Query Dropdownlist in VB.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, linq

I have bound my data source to the drop down list and it works, but it is showing duplicates. Here is my code

```
Private Sub ddlMasterPids_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlMasterPids.Load
    Dim db As New DesignConstructionDataContext

    Dim Master = (From Master_Name In db.groups
                  Where (Master_Name.Master_Name IsNot Nothing)
                  Select Master_Name).ToList().Distinct()

    ddlMasterPids.DataSource = Master
    ddlMasterPids.DataTextField = "Master_Name"
    ddlMasterPids.DataValueField = "Master_Name"
    ddlMasterPids.DataBind()
End Sub
```

The .Distinct() does not throw an error, but there are still duplicates. I also tried switching the distinc and tolist, but still just ignored the distinct. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you call `Distinct` after `ToList`? That fills all into memory before it removes duplicates. Instead let the database skip duplicates. What is `Master_Name` at all, a `String`?

Comment: `Master_Name` is a string, and I tried putting Distinct before ToList but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not selecting the column `Master_Name` but the row in the table `Master_Name`. That why `Distinct` doesn't work as expected. The rows have at least one column that is different.

Instead you want this:

```
Dim Master = (From Master_Name In db.groups
              Where Master_Name.Master_Name IsNot Nothing
              Select Master_Name.Master_Name).Distinct().ToList()
```

Note also that i call `Distinct` before `ToList` to filter already in the database.

Comment: hmm... I tried that and now it's giving me an error at `DataBind()` saying `System.String does not contain a property with the name Master_Name`

Comment: @kelseywhiting: i must admit that i don't really understand your query. What is `Master_Name.Master_Name` and what is `Master_Name In db.groups`? Confusing namings.

Comment: I'm trying to get a drop down list of all the projects in my database that are located in the collumn `Master_Name` I just named my variable Master_Name as well. I want the list to skip nulls and duplicates.. I'm super new to asp.net. I'm a little confused about linq and databinding

Comment: @kelseywhiting that's confusing. In the interest of getting helpful answers, rename your variables in your question so others can understand.

Comment: Tim has selected just the column `Master_Name` for you. You now have a distinct list of **string**. You don't need to select the field for data binding. Remove the two lines between `DataSource` and `DataBind`.

Comment: Great!! Thank you, that worked. Sorry, I am very new to programming in general.